# ElasticSearch - index change not flushed

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch, node-modules

I use the elasticsearch module in typescript, and for some reason, the changes I apply to the indexes (or even the new documents I insert) are not detected by the code...

Here's an example bellow:

```js
        try {
            await this._client.indices.delete({
                index: 'databases, schemas, tables',
                ignore_unavailable: true
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error trying to delete the indexes...');
            console.error(err);
        }

        try {
            await this._client.indices.create({ index: 'databases' });
            await this._client.indices.create({ index: 'schemas' });
            await this._client.indices.create({ index: 'tables' });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error trying to create the indexes...');
            console.error(err);
        }

        try {
            await this._client.indices.flush({
                index: 'databases, schemas, tables',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error trying to flush...');
            console.error(err);
        }
```

The result of this code is:

```
Error trying to create the indexes...
ResponseError: resource_already_exists_exception
...

Error trying to flush...
ResponseError: index_not_found_exception
...
```

So this really makes no sense to me.. Am i missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be flushing indexes with a comma delimited string, you should try passing the list of indexes as an array:

```
await this._client.indices.flush({
                index: ['databases', 'schemas', 'tables']
            })
```